# PHP script on webserver printing in office

Tags: php, printing

I'm running a PHP script on my webserver. When an order happens online I'd like for a receipt printer to print the order at work.

Right now the PHP script create an email with the order information, then a dedicated computer running an email program checks for new emails every x minutes. If it sees a new email, it prints the content to the receipt printer.

This is slow, as the email program has to pull new emails at x intervals, so a printout can be sitting in the queue for a while. It's also insecure, as anyone with the email address can send order details directly.

Is there a better way for my script to print order information?

Comment: What OS do you run? Is your PHP server connected to the printer?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so from what i understand, you have two systems. The first one takes the order and second one prints. Now if you don't want to go with mail , you can create a job queue with redis backend or something that invokes when a new job in added from your webserver.

[php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) is a nice place to get started on the same.